# Find files with particular filename format, cat each one with a header file, and save result to original file for each such file

Tags: cat, xargs

I have a bunch of html files and I want to cat them all (individually) with a header file (several lines at least in length), say header.txt. I'm almost there. I can cat each file with the header file with the following command, but how can I then output the result to save it under the original filename?

```
find . -iname "*.html" | xargs -L 1 cat header.txt
```

The above prints out what I want, but how can I then reference the `xargs` argument to add a final > original file name?

So in short, I want to insert the text from header.txt into the beginning of every html file. Can I modify the above command to do so? Or alternately are there other ways to achieve this?

---

As an update, here's what I've tried since posting, which hasn't worked:

```
find . -iname "*.html" | xargs -L 1 cat header.txt {} > {}.new
```

This does fine except it prints to a file literally named `{}.new`. That file looks as it should but this isn't helpful.

Also tried @Dave's suggestion, but there is a syntax error I can't fix:

```
 find . -iname "*.html" -exec (cat header.txt; cat {}) > {}.new
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: This sounds like you want to insert the `header.txt` at the beginning of all your `*.html` files. Have I understood you correctly?

Comment: Maybe you want to reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533679/how-to-insert-a-text-at-the-beginning-of-a-file. Similar idea except the text you're adding is from `cat`ing a file and you're performing a `find`. I would lean towards something like `find . -iname "*.html" -exec (cat header.txt; cat {}) > {}.new` I would also check over the new files before scripting them to overwrite the originals. (I didn't test that command, it was meant to give an idea)

Comment: @roaima yes that's exactly it. I added the clarification to the original question. Thanks.

Comment: @Dave thanks for the suggestion. Will try that out now.

Comment: @sunny Now that I'm thinking about it `awk` may also be a good tool for this, as you can insert text at line 1 using it

Comment: @roaima I'd say adding to the start of a file is different because you can't take the same luxuries, the biggest difference being that concatenation in place will not work: `cat header file > file` throws an error, and so command grouping is required

Comment: @roaima thanks for the link. I am having a difficult time translating their recommendations about adding a string into recommendations about adding a file. It's not obvious how to make it work.

Comment: @Dave I tried out your example but it keeps saying "unexpected symbol (" in response to the (exec

Comment: @don_crissti the header file is several lines.

Comment: On that link I've suggested, look at the answer from `rook`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to insert the text from header.txt into the beginning of every html file.

To prepend the contents of `header.txt` to all HTML files, use this oneliner:

```
for i in `find . -name '*.html'` ; do cat /path/to/header.txt > "$i".tmp && cat "$i" >> "$i".tmp && mv "$i".tmp "$i" ; done
```

Contents of `1.html`:

```
first html file contents
```

Contents of `header.txt`:

```
my header
```

Contents of `1.html` after running the script:

```
my header
first html file contents
```

(I've tested it, but do backup your files just in case.)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop, like the following:

```
find . -iname "*.html" | while read line; do cat header.txt "$line" > "${line}.new" ; done
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. It almost did the trick but it deposited the files in files with the literal ".new" at the end, which is definitely easy to fix in a second line anyhow.